# Get wired MAC address from computer/server

Tags: networking, powershell, mac-address

I am thinking about using the wired MAC-adr as a unique value in a program. So i need to be sure the MAC-adr is the wired one and NOT the wireless.

```
$mac = gwmi -computer $compname win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select MACAddress
```

This is what I started with, but it gives me two addresses.
First one is the one I want: 00:00:11:11:22:22
The last one is the wireless address: 00:1F:3C:8E:61:D8

I can't just sort like: select -first 1. Because I don't know what this will get me on other computers..
And btw, this DOES work on ipV6 as well as ipV4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$mac = gwmi -computer $compname win32_NetworkAdapter | ? { $_.AdapterType -match "802.3" } |  select MACAddress
```

If there's more than one you need to do a selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific, for example:

```
(gwmi win32_NetworkAdapter -computer $compname -filter "NetConnectionID='Local Area Connection'").MACAddress
```