# Batch file hanging

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

I am trying to get a batch file to output some data to a CSV file. The command I have works perfectly in the command line but not when I copy it to a batch file. When run, it just hangs and repeats itself it the CSV file.

Here is the batch script:

```
getmac /fo csv /nh >> C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test.csv
```

What I am trying to do is run this script on all the new lab computers that we have and generate a list of mac addresses that we can use to reserve IPs in the DHCP server.

Ideally, I would like the computer name as well but thats not really needed.
I am running Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: What are you naming the batch script?

Comment: "echo %COMPUTERNAME%" for the computer name.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/10583535/291641 for some powershell suggestions. Note you can run this on remote machines using the /S argument (or specify the machine in powershell commands).

Comment: The reason I asked for the name of your batch script is because naming the script the same as a command will cause your script to be called in an infinite loop rather than calling the command. getmac.bat calls getmac (which will be getmac.bat since that overrides the getmac program) calls getmac ...  If so, just change the name of your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic /node:@"%userprofile%\desktop\computername.txt" /failfast:on nicconfig where ipenabled=true get caption,macaddress,ipaddress /format:csv
```

Lists node (computername), IPAddress, MACAddress, and the description of the NIC.

To generate a list of computers that are turned on,

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %A >> "%userprofile%\desktop\computername.txt"
```

See `wmic /?`, `wmic nicconfig /?`, `wmic nicconfig get /?`, `wmic nicconfig set /?`, `wmic nicconfig call /?`, `wmic /format /?`, `wmic /node /?`, `wmic /failfast /?`, `for /?`, and `findstr /?`.